# Replace all matches for a regular expression except for the first one

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm not sure if this is possible only with `preg_replace` function but I would like to get only the first image and ignore all the other.

This code excludes all images in the text I want to display, but I need to get only the first image.

```
if (!$params->get('image')) {
    $item->introtext = preg_replace('/<img[^>]*>/', '', $item->introtext);
}
```

Can you please point me to the right direction to achieve this?

---

**EDIT :**

It seems that using the `limit` property is not enough since I don't want to skip the 1st image and keep the remaining. I need the opposite: Keep the 1st image and replace all the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to accomplish that. This function will execute a callback function you pass as parameter that will return a replacement string for every match it founds in your original string.

In this case, we will return the own match in the first occurrence so it will not be replaced.

```
$i = 0;
$item->introtext = preg_replace_callback('/<img[^>]*>/', function($match) use (&$i) {
    if ($i++ == 0) // compares $i to 0 and then increment it
        return $match[0]; // if $i is equal to 0, return the own match

    return ''; // otherwise, return an empty string to replace your match
}, $item->introtext);
```

Comment: If I set the limit to `1`, this will exclude only the 1st image and keep the remaining. If I set the limit to `2`, it will exclude the first 2 images and keep the others, correct? I need to keep the 1st image only

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding your question. I edited the answer to regard what you really want it to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm. Now I need to study what you've posted because I don't really understand the logic.

Comment: I've added some comments to help you understand it. You can also debug it inspecting the variable values in the callback function to realize what's going on inside it.

Comment: perfect! now I get it. `$match[0]` is the 1st instance of the image tag so it keeps it intact. Thanks for your help and your explanation! I appreciate it